# What is Windows 7 "Anytime Upgrade"

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, anytime-upgrade, windows-edition

What is the difference between the [Windows 7 Anytime Upgrade](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832116772&cm_re=windows_7_ultimate_upgrade-_-32-116-772-_-Product) and the [Windows 7 Upgrade](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832116715&cm_re=windows_7_ultimate_upgrade-_-32-116-715-_-Product).  If I have Vista ultimate and want to go to Windows 7 Ultimate which should I get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Upgrade` is for Vista and XP users who would like to move to Windows 7.

`Anytime Upgrade` is for users who already own Windows 7, and would like to upgrade to a higher model, such as from Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 7 Ultimate.

You need Upgrade, not Anytime Upgrade.